# showing that ordinal successor function is one-to-one

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wondered if someone could help me to show that if A and B are ordinals, and A+ = B+ (where X+ is X u {X}), then A = B -- i.e., that the ordinal successor function is one-to-one.  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Hint: $A$ is the union of elements of its successor (why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $A^+=B^+$, and $A\ne B$, then $A\in B$ and $B\in A$. Assuming that you know that ordinals are transitive sets, it’s now very easy to get a contradiction.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!

Comment: @davidp: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I do not think this is true. If you are assuming that $A^{+} = B^{+}$ and $A \neq B$, then you can't have both $A \in B$ and $B \in A$. It has to be one or the other. Would you get your contradiction then??